# Multi groups query LDAP in otrs

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, otrs

I need to filter LDAP records to access otrs like

```
((cn=branch)and(cn=department)or(cn=admins))
```

(cn=department) isn't an authentizing condition, it's a filter of otrs groups. It's on the same level of LDAP path as (cn=branch) and (cn=admins):

> cn=branchA,ou=groups 
>   cn=admins,ou=groups 
>   cn=departmentD,ou=groups

I've tried to use a filter

```
$Self->{'AuthModule::LDAP::AlwaysFilter'} = '(|(cn=branchA)(cn=admins))';
```

that is the result a user logging LDAP filter in log:

```
(&(cn=usernameX)(|(cn=branchA)(cn=admins)))
```

It seems to be right but not working, usernameX's access is denied even he is in one or both of the groups.

I've used many variations of syntax including `(&(|(objectclass=posixGroup))(|(cn=admins)(cn=branchA)))` - this syntax running on our nextcloud file server, but no success in otrs.

Any idea?

otrs 5 on ubuntu 16.04, openldap

Comment: The filter (&(cn=usernameX)(|(cn=branchA)(cn=admins))) can never be true unless there's an object with cn=usernameX and cn=branchA or admins. Are you doing group membership? You might need something like (&(cn=usernameX)(member=admins)) and if you only want to search on the branchA subtree, then you'll need to set the baseDN of the search to branchA.